# Cleanup apache config for Lion Server

Tags: macos, osx-server, serveradmin

I have installed Lion Server on my box.  (broke my existing VPN setup, and I wanted to play around with it).

I had a bunch of stuff already setup in apache (some webdav for omnifocus, ical, etc).  Due to my customizations (I'm assuming) the server manager can't really do anything with apache (no ical, webdav, wiki, etc).  What do I need to do to reset to a place where the Lion server software is happy with the way I've got my box setup?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can restore the web server to factory settings.

1. Turn off the Web Server service
2. Open Terminal and run `sudo serveradmin command web:command=restoreFactorySettings`
3. Enter your administrator password
4. Restart Web Server service.

Comment: thanks, that seemed to do it.  Sorry it took me so long to get back.

Answer (score 1):

If that didn't do the trick,

1. turn off everything which uses Apache (Wiki, iCal-Server ...)
2. run the following command

   ```
   sudo /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/ServerFoundation.framework/Resources/xswebconfig restorefactorysettings
   ```

The answer using `serveradmin` to reset factory defaults calls the xswebconfig and sometimes you need to force the lower level reset and consider other web based services that may lock and prevent a shutdown of the service.

Comment: Can you explain what this does?